# Hide url segment of azure b2c

Tags: url-rewriting, azure-ad-b2c, azure-front-door

Is it possible to hide url segment of azure b2c url? I have custom domain and I was forced to use Azure Front Door service. I see this service has url rewrite feature, so possible instead of this url

```
https://login.mydomain.com/tenant-id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_SIGNIN&client_id=..
```

I can have something like this

```
https://login.mydomain.com?p=B2C_1A_SIGNIN&client_id=..
```

Or even this (add default parameters if they not presented in original url)

```
https://login.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 3):

As Dave says, you cannot manipulate the URL in this way, but there are other things you can do if you're just looking something prettier.

You can use your custom domain instead of the yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com or the tenant guid, which *may* look better. For example, if you buy another domain you could have `https://login.mydomain.com/apko.xyz/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`.

Moreover, any query parameters can be sent in the body of a HTTP POST request so you'd end up with a much cleaner URL: `POST https://login.mydomain.com/tenant-id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

Comment: Can you use a custom domain instead of `yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com` or the tenant GUID? I thought a limitation of B2C was that you had to [include one of those in the URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#optional-use-tenant-id)? Though I must confess, I don't tend to be the one setting up custom domains so all I've got to go on here are the docs which aren't always the most accurate.

Comment: Yep! As long as it's in your custom domains on the B2C tenant you can use it instead of youtenant.onmicrosoft.com and the tenant guid - here's a login link to my dev tenant login using the custom domain: https://dee2c.b2clogin.com/dee2c.dev/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_google_or_local&client_id=08dc35be-944f-42f2-a86d-48595cc91895&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login